# SpringBoot version 1.3.x to 1.4.0.RELEASE - Error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, camunda

I have update Spring Boot version from 1.3.5 to 1.4.0 and I am getting the below error

Using Camunda BPM and the versions are
    Spring-Boot:  (v1.4.0.RELEASE)
    Camunda BPM: (v7.5.0)
    Camunda BPM Spring Boot Starter: (v1.2.1)

The dependency for camunda ,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

For packaging we are using the below plugin,

```
        <plugin>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>    
             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>              
             <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>               
             <configuration>                       
                <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                <layout>ZIP</layout>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

[localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.b.c.e.tomcat.TomcatStarter - Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.CamundaBpmWebappAutoConfiguration': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.CamundaBpmWebappAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$59b2932d]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter: method <init>()V not found 
[main] WARN  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springramework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat 
[main] WARN  o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Error handling failed (org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5609159b has not been refreshed yet) 
[main] WARN  o.c.b.s.b.s.r.JobExecutorRunListener - skipping because of failed context initialization 
[main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed 
[main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed 
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
at com.nagravision.myapp.MainApplication.main(MainApplication.java:20)
 Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:116)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:83)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:530)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:176)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.CamundaBpmWebappAutoConfiguration': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.CamundaBpmWebappAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$59b2932d]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter: method <init>()V not found
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:233)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:214)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:90)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:78)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:241)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:228)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:89)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:213)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:55)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.CamundaBpmWebappAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$59b2932d]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter: method <init>()V not found
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter: method <init>()V not found
at org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.CamundaBpmWebappAutoConfiguration.<init>(CamundaBpmWebappAutoConfiguration.java:24)
at org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.CamundaBpmWebappAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$59b2932d.<init>(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
... 35 common frames omitted
```

Please let me know what will be the reason for failing for updating from 1.3.x to 1.4.0 spring boot

Comment: Does CamundaBpm support V1.4? The error is on - CamundaBpmWebappAutoConfiguration

Comment: For camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp dependency there is a support for spring-boot-starter-web with 1.4.0.RELEASE . Please check the link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.camunda.bpm.extension/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp/1.2.1  and please let me know how can we can confirm that there is no support for spring-boot v1.4.0.RELEASE.

Comment: https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter lists a pom.xml bug fix to only work on 1.3.7

Comment: 1.4 is an enhancement request https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter/issues/117 which contains your issue

Answer (score 1):

Camuda BPM only supports up to Spring Boot - 1.3.7

[Camunda BPM](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter/commit/09090a71db0256f31df94137db7e8dc99f8be62e)

Comment: We are planning to switch to java 8 and spring boot 1.4 with the 2.0 release, but currently that statement is correct.